# Change button style

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I have three buttons and three panels.i click button panel1 only load at the time,panel2 and 3 are invisible.if i click button2 panel2 load,panel1 and 3 are invisible.i want to change my button style like tabcontainer of tabs.these three button like to show tabs.is it possible in css with asp.net?

Comment: In order for anyone to help you, you need to post relevant html/css/js

Comment: of course it is possible.

Comment: it is possible with jquery or javascript

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show/ & http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: If you know css coding means please help me,and how to call into button?that 3 buttons like to show tabs in tabcontainer.is it possible?reply me

Comment: make [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a concept of [Togglable tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
<script>
$('#panel a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})

// first active
$('#panel a:first').tab('show');
</script>

<div class="tabbable">
<ul id="panel" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li><a href="#button1" data-toggle="tab">Button 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#button2" data-toggle="tab">Button 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#button3" data-toggle="tab">Button 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="button1">
     You have click button 1 and show a panel 1 </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="button2">You have click button 2 and show a panel 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="button3">You have click button 3 and show a panel 3 </div> 
</div>
```

Here's demo : <kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/9C5TR/1/)**</kbd>